# Defining the operator < in a class for a map (c++)

Tags: c++, dictionary

So I have a class:

```
class Time{
    private:
    string day;
    string hour;
    public:
    //etc
    }
```

I've defined in the class:

```
bool Time::operator <(const Time &t1) const {
     if (day!= t1.see_day()) {
        return day < t1.see_day();
     }
     else return hour < t1.see_hour;
}
```

When I compile it gives me an error:

> "error passing 'const Time' as 'this' argument of std::string Time::see_day()" discards qualifiers[-fpermissive].

I want this just for creating an iterator to write all the map in an ascending order. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to mark your

```
Time::see_day() const
//              ^^^^^
//             needs to be const
```

as otherwise in the line

```
return day < t1.see_day();
```

you try to invoke a non-`const` member function on a `const` instance (`t1` in this case), and that is forbidden, hence the error.

Same issue with `Time::see_hour()` (you also have a typo, missing parentheses for the function call).

Comment: @xampla no problem, this is a frequent error you'll see again and again ;)